# htaccess Redirect a Specific Directory URLs to another different URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

With `.htaccess` how to redirect `from`:

- http://apple.example.com/old_folder
- http://apple.example.com/old_folder/
- http://apple.example.com/old_folder/bla/bla/bla?a=b&etc

whatever depths under `apple.example.com/old_folder` --> `to`:

- http://banana.example.com/new_folder/

.. only?

I used following code, but not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apple.example.com/old_folder$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://banana.example.com/new_folder/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match URI in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` condition.

This rule should work from root .htaccess of `apple.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apple\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old_folder(/|$) http://banana.example.com/new_folder/? [R,L]
```

**EDIT:** OR else use this rule in `/old_folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^ http://banana.example.com/new_folder/? [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But sorry, i have made a little changes in the domain names.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the rule still can not work. Please kindly check with ( http://htaccess.madewithlove.be ) Every sub-folders under `apple` are being hit :S

Comment: Never test on that site, its not at all reliable. Test it on your localhost.

Comment: But then i have tested on my Development Server already. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: This is one of the simplest rule. I have tested it also before posting. You have to make sure that .htaccess is enabled. Also you can try placing **EDITed** rule in `/old_folder/.htaccess`